# Header with sectionname

Tags: header-footer

I would like to have the name of the section in the headers of my latex article. Ideally centered, italic, not all caps and without the number of the section. I found that I could use

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
```

And then it should work with `\chead{}`. But I don't know what I have to write into those brackets. I tried `\nameref` and `\titleref` and i gave all sections a label but I only get an error message. Would be great if someone could help me out!

My arcticle looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\chead{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{name of section 1}
...
\end{document}
```

Like this it doesn't work of course because the brackets of `\chead{}` are empty.

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far.

Comment: In particular, do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: I edited my post, I use `\documentclass{article}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markboth{\hfill#1\hfill}{}}
\fancyhead[L]{\sectionmark}
\begin{document}
\section{Gnus}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Gnat}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Quick and dirty though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is almost what I wanted! The only problem now is, that every subsection beyond the first doesn't have a header now. I would like that it shows just the section name in every single subsection without the name of the subsection..
I also removed the line now with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` after your code.

Comment: @Kegorus If you think the answer helped, do not say thank you but approve it instead. Your additionnal problem is unclear to me. Please post a MWE showing what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one section starting on a page, which one should be in the header?

1. Last section on a page should be in page header -> use `\leftmark` and redefine `sectionmark` using `\markboth`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\section{Foo}
\blindtext
\section{Bar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

2. First section on a page should be in page header -> use `\rightmark`, redefine `\sectionmark` using `\markright` and redefine `\subsectionmark` to do nothing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\section{Foo}
\blindtext
\section{Bar}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```